# How to compile an individual jsp file from command line

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, oc4j

The current application server is OC4J where the JSP files are pre compiled. There is change in the text that needs to be made in the jsp files. Is there a way to compile a individual file(contact.jsp) to contact.class , because we don't want a new build due to deployment issues!!

Comment: Are you asking how to compile without redeploying and see the changes, or just get the .class file without redeploying?

Comment: Use jspc command.View this link for more details http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0790/abxcc/index.html

Comment: I want to pre-compile the jsp file and replace it with the old class file?

Comment: I am using 1.5 jdk to compile it.I dont have this jspc in install_dir/bin/https/bin . I get jspc is not recognized as internal or external command